# Is it possible to include two different java package and use their API?

Tags: java, package

I just want to know if it is possible to use two different package of java in a single project. For example there are two or more java package for neural network. Is it possible for
me to use those all packages for a single project? There is one package called stat which 
includes many API for statistical operation.May I include those all in a project like incluing
different header files in C programming and use those interchangeably?

Any concise source of quickly java learning material would be very much beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use any number of APIs in a Java program; the only related thing I can think of that you cannot do is use packages that have the exact same fully-qualified name, and all the APIs I've ever seen make sure they don't duplicate others.

For instance, if you have two APIs that both have classes named Network, that is ok as long as they come from different packages -- one could be com.x.base.something.Network, and the other com.y.base.something.Network -- as long as the fully qualified name is different, you can use them both in your program.

Depending on what you mean by "quickly", there is no way I know of to learn any significant portion of java in a few days or weeks.  It's a big collection of significant technologies, it's just going to take some time.